# Magento 2: Get Product Collection by Dropdown Value

Tags: magento2, php, product-collection

How do you get a collection of products based on the drop down attribute value instead of the id?

```
....
protected $collectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
) {
    ...
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

protected function checkProducts()
{    
    $product = $this->collectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('new_product_status', ['eq' => 254]) // filter by value instead of id here
    ->setPageSize(1)
    ->getFirstItem();  
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up solving this with the following:

Just needed to implement `\Magento\Eav\Model\Config` and grab the option ID by it's text / label value.

```
....
protected $collectionFactory;
protected $eavConfig;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
) {
    ...
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
}

protected function checkProducts()
{    
    $product = $this->collectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('new_product_status')
    ->addFieldToFilter('new_product_status', array('eq' => $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'new_product_status')->getSource()->getOptionId('Label Text Value Here')))
    ->setPageSize(1)
    ->getFirstItem();  
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like (using **`addAttributeToFilter`**):

```
->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=>'new_product_status','eq'=>'254')
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks -- the code in the OP works, I'm trying to get `new_product_status` by the option label value, instead of the `id`

Answer (score 0):

To get product collection using dropdown attribute use dropdown option ID instead of Label.

**For example:**  Your drop down attribute Name is **ABC** and dropdown options is **popular** and attribute option ID is **56** so your code should be like below.

```
$productcollection = $this->productCollection
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('ABC', 56) //where ABC= attribute name & 56 is attribute option id
->load();
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! But I'm actually trying to get the attribute by option label value instead of it's `id`

Comment: But in the question, you have mentioned get product collection by drop down. and now you are asking for something else.

Comment: I am looking to get it by the dropdown but the label value (not id) -- in OP my code works to get by dropdown option ID, not dropdown option label text value

Comment: Okay i will get back to you with solution.

Comment: Thanks, however I just posted an answer that seems to work now unless you have something more efficient?